# How to optimize intranet web site

Tags: optimization, web, system, intranet

I have create a web site (PHP, MySQL) for the intranet of my campus. The campus network has a proxy and web servers but I've used a PC in my workgroup as the server using XAMPP 1.7.7 for testing purpose. When I visiting the web site from the different PC in the same workgroup it takes more than 30 seconds to load the index page or other pages.

The web browser used is Firefox and it has bypass the proxy server for the local addresses. The index.php page is only 5KB of the size. And in the index.php I have destroyed current session if there any, database connection to retrieve latest 03 news and call two external css files. Used less than 5 images (total capacity less than 5 KB) in every page. The XAMPP is in default settings.

Is there something that I can do to optimize and decrease the loading time. Your opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

That is very slow.  Your page is not that large.  If the page loads fast locally don't bother trying to optimize more.    How long does it take to copy a file over the workgroup?  Or better yet, FTP a file to your 'server'?

You could use tracert (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162326) to get a better idea where the slow down is.

More generally speaking, the ideal solution really depends on what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.  XAMPP is obviously more geared towards personal localhost work.   You got the ports open and host all setup correctly, seems your immediate problem is a network issue requiring further diagnoses.

Comment: Thanks ficuscr for your quick reply. Network speed is good (In my workgroup). It copies 100MB less than a minute(copy and paste over the network not using ftp). I used XAMPP to test the system with the users. I'll check with tracert command.

Comment: Also you did read the section at  http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html titled, "A matter of security (A MUST READ!)"?

Comment: Final suggestions would be check its not software firewalls or anti virus.  Double check the etc/hosts and maybe a give it a good ole `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Yes I did. But I didn't consider that much since I just wanted to test the system in real life situations. And tracert gave me following result.   

Tracing route to *** [10.18.*.**]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  *** [10.18.*.**]

Trace complete.